# Flutter Registration with API

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I successfully can login with my API connection also can display the data in my app.

I follow the same method for the registration to send data in API So that I can login.

But the registration is not happening, although it didn't show any error.  My SnackBar showing `You are already registered` . But When I try to login *with the data which I provided in registration form, its showing user not found*( Obvious reason registration process didn't perform). Is there any problem with my API MODEL?

Here is my Parameters

```
 {

    "Email":"qwer@gmail.com",
    "Mobile":"1237891",
    "Password":"9991",
    "RetypePassword":"9991"

}
```

And here is the Json response

```
 {
    "Status": "1",
    "Message": "You are registered successfully",
    "UserData": {
        "Name": "qwer@gmail.com",
        "EncUserId": "IS0QOCrLby8Ft1kbkzn/mg=="
    }
}
```

After that I created a registration form, when user click the `Register` button it's run my API function `registrationOfuser()`

```
Future <void> registrationOfuser(String  email, contact, pass,conpass) async{
    var jsonResponse ;
    Map data = {
      
      'Email': email,
      'Mobile': contact,
      'Password': pass,
      'RetypePassword': conpass,
    };
    print(data);

     String body = json.encode(data);
    var url = 'http://myurl/home/djkjkfjkjfwkjfkwjkjfkjwjfkwjfkwf';
    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      body: body,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
    );

    print(response.body);
    print(response.statusCode);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:Text(" ${jsonResponse['Message']}"))) ;      
         
      //Or put here your next screen using Navigator.push() method
      print('success');
    } else {
      print('error');
    }



}
```

And here is my MODEL

```
    class RegistrationApiResponse {
    RegistrationApiResponse({
        required this.status,
        required this.message,
        required this.userData,
    });

    String status;
    String message;
    //UserData userData;
    UserData? userData;

    factory RegistrationApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => RegistrationApiResponse(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
         userData: json["UserData"] == null? null:UserData.fromJson(json["UserData"] as Map<String, dynamic>),
        
       


}

class UserData {
    UserData({
        required this.name,
        required this.encUserId,
    });

    String name;
    String encUserId;

    factory UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserData(
        name: json["Name"],
        encUserId: json["EncUserId"],
    );

}
```

Comment: What are you receiving at response.statusCode after trying to call to the register URL?

Comment: Not printing  my status code now, its showing`Exception has occurred.
_CastError (type 'TextEditingController' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)`

Comment: In order to access to the data in your TextEditingController you should access them by using controllerName.value.text

Comment: the status is 200 now, but its always showing `User already  registered` although I provide  totally new data in my registration form

Comment: check before sending the form that the data that you are sending is the same that is shown in the registration form view.

Comment: Yes. I'm providing totally new data for each field.. every time showing `You already registered`  meanwhile I can't login with those data

Comment: Check in your database if those new registered data is, in fact, created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to below code help:

**Create TextEditingController**

```
  final TextEditingController email = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController contact = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController password = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController conpassword = new TextEditingController();
```

**Create one function for registration**

```
register(String  email, contact, pass,conpass) async {
    Map data = {
      
      'Email': email,
      'Mobile': contact,
      'Password': pass,
      'RetypePassword': conpass,
    };
    print(data);

    String body = json.encode(data);
    var url = 'Your url here';
    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      body: body,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
    );
    print(response.body);
    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //Or put here your next screen using Navigator.push() method
      print('success');
    } else {
      print('error');
    }
  }
```

Create Button

```
ElevatedButton(
child:Text('Register'),
onPressed:(){
   register(email.text, contact.text, password.text, conpassword.text);
   },
),
```

Comment: Ok. Its now statuscode 200/success.  But  in my console its showing `{"Status":"0","Message":"You are already registered","UserData":null}`  although  I provided new username password.  I updated the code with your

Comment: try to change your data or add different data like email,contact etc

Comment: YES.  I use totally different data for each field like email,phone,pasword . Still  showing `You are already registered` But when I try to Login its telling  my `user not found`, which means data didn't go to the API?

Comment: API responding fine with new data. `{
    "Status": "1",
    "Message": "You are registered successfully",
    "UserData": {
        "Name": "qwert@gmail.com",
        "EncUserId": "evaCGQUWUt6RPoU6ODXDsQ=="
    }
}`

Comment: can you share your API url?

Comment: here is the parameters `{

    "Email":"qwert@gmail.com",
    "Mobile":"12378912",
    "Password":"99912",
    "RetypePassword":"99912"

}`

Comment: give me a time i will test

Comment: Ok. Not sure about the parameters name though . Does it even matter ? I tried with different Parameters name like -> instead of `"RetypePassword":"99912"`  I put `"Retypepassword":"99912"` also work  in postman.

Comment: can you check your db my entry is added or not? my response is like `{Email: qw@gmail.com, Mobile: 1213, Password: aa, RetypePassword: aa}
`

Comment: I can't check DB. But I can login with your Id Password. Means probably you add in DB.  its showing  `You successfully Login`

Comment: which id and password

Comment: `qw@gmail.com`  ` aa`

Comment: id = `qw@gmail.com` and password = `aa`

Comment: `{"Status":"1","Message":"You are registered successfully","UserData":{"Name":"qw@gmail.com","EncUserId":"diG1mSDJE4UDwBeAPp315w=="}}`

Comment: @Tuhin please check this code on this [url](https://pastebin.com/KuRTdcAU) test it on your machine , I have paste the code and I also test on my machine

Comment: yes! it's doing fine on my machine.. Maybe I need to debug my code now

Comment: Hi Ravindra your answer helped me a lot with the registration, it worked perfectly but I am now having some difficulties when trying to do make my login page work. Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: @Panashe, share/ask your problem

Comment: I am trying to make it so that a user can login and logout of my app, I have tried several methods but they all seem to not work this is one of the method's I tried a few days ago, but there are some errors. Is there any method that you know that might work?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72113045/flutter-login-page-authentication-using-mysql?noredirect=1#comment127418838_72113045

Comment: @Panashe check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72167364/13997210) on your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72113045/13997210)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get text from controller. Do as follows:

```
body:({
    'Email':emailController.text,
    'Mobile':phoneController.text,
    'Password':passwordController.text,
    'RetypePassword':rePasswordController.text,
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApiService {
  callloginapi(
    var email,
  ) async {
    LoginReg? userModel;

    Response response = await post(
        Uri.parse('http://13.127.138.139/api/Login_Register_User'),
        body: {
          'mobile': email,
        });

    var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    userModel = LoginReg.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print(jsonResponse['token']);
    var flag = jsonResponse['data']['flag'];
    log('==========flag ===========$flag');
    //return userModel;
    var message = jsonResponse['message'];
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (flag == 'true') {
        Get.offAllNamed(PageRoutes.home);
        // t
        emailController.clear();
        print('$message');

        // moveToHome(context);

      } else {
        // server error
        print('Not Register');
      }

    }
  }}
```