# Flutter failed to post data to create user with API

Tags: flutter, api

I try to create user using api but it throws an exception when executed.

So, here is my json response as below.

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "user": {
    "user_id": "612f02fc4ae19",
    "name": "Test User3",
    "mobile": "8347406873",
    "email": "dhaval@gmail.com",
    "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
    "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344",
    "location": "Vyara",
    "created_at": "2021-09-01"
  },
  "msg": "Your account has been created successfully."
}
```

As response i created model class as below in signup_model.dart file.

```
import 'dart:convert';

SignupModel signupModelFromJson(String str) =>
    SignupModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String signupModelToJson(SignupModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class SignupModel {
  SignupModel({
    this.success,
    this.user,
    this.msg,
  });

  int? success;
  UserRegistration? user;
  String? msg;

  factory SignupModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SignupModel(
        success: json["success"],
        user: UserRegistration.fromJson(json["user"]),
        msg: json["msg"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "user": user?.toJson(),
        "msg": msg,
      };
}

class UserRegistration {
  UserRegistration({
    this.userId,
    this.name,
    this.mobile,
    this.email,
    this.standardId,
    this.mediumId,
    this.location,
    this.createdAt,
  });

  String? userId;
  String? name;
  String? mobile;
  String? email;
  String? standardId;
  String? mediumId;
  String? location;
  DateTime? createdAt;

  factory UserRegistration.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      UserRegistration(
        userId: json["user_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        mobile: json["mobile"],
        email: json["email"],
        standardId: json["standard_id"],
        mediumId: json["medium_id"],
        location: json["location"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "user_id": userId,
        "name": name,
        "mobile": mobile,
        "email": email,
        "standard_id": standardId,
        "medium_id": mediumId,
        "location": location,
        "created_at":
            "${createdAt?.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${createdAt?.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${createdAt?.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
      };
}
```

Function which i created as below in api_manager.dart file.

```
Future<UserRegistration> createUser(
    String name,
    String email,
    String mobile,
    String standardId,
    String mediumId,
  ) async {
    final registrationUrl = "$baseUrl/user/register";
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(registrationUrl),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'mobile': mobile,
        'standard_id': standardId,
        'medium_id': mediumId,
      }),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      return UserRegistration.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to create User.');
    }
  }
```

And My signup screen Code as below in signup_screen.dart file.

```
class _SignUp1State extends State<SignUp1> {
  final baseUrl = SankalpApi().baseUrl;

  bool value = false;
  var _standards = <Standard>[];
  var _mediums = <Medium>[];
  Standard? selectedStandard;
  Medium? selectedMedium;

  var standardId;
  var mediumId;

  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _mobileController = TextEditingController();

  Future<UserRegistration>? userRegistration;

  GlobalKey<FormState> _globalFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool isApiCallProcess = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ApiManager().getStandards().then((standards) {
      setState(() {
        _standards = standards;
      });
    });
  }

  void onMediumChange(standard) {
    setState(() {
      selectedStandard = standard;
      _mediums = [];
    });
    String mediumUrl =
        "$baseUrl/medium/get_by_course_id?standard_id=${selectedStandard?.standardId}";
    ApiManager().getMediums(mediumUrl).then((List<Medium> value) => {
          setState(() {
            _mediums = value;
          })
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Shader linearGradient = LinearGradient(
      colors: <Color>[
        Color(0xff8921aa),
        Color(0xffDA44bb),
      ],
    ).createShader(new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 70.0));

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(
        key: _globalFormKey,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 30),
              Text(
                'Learn from wide range of videos and tutorials',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  color: Colors.grey[600],
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Full Name"),
                controller: _nameController,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return "Name is required.";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  //this.userRegistration.name = value.toString().trim();
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
                controller: _emailController,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Email is required.';
                  }
                  if (!RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]")
                      .hasMatch(value)) {
                    return 'Enter valid Email';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  //this.userRegistration.email = value.toString().trim();
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Mobile Number"),
                controller: _mobileController,
                validator: (value) {
                  String pattern = r'(^[0-9]*$)';
                  RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
                  if (value!.length == 0) {
                    return "Mobile is required";
                  } else if (value.length != 10) {
                    return "Mobile number must 10 digits";
                  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
                    return "Mobile Number must be digits";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  //this.userRegistration.mobile = value.toString().trim();
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              DropdownButtonFormField<Standard>(
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null) {
                    return "Select Standard";
                  }
                },
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: Text('Select Standard'),
                value: selectedStandard,
                items: _standards.map((Standard standard) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<Standard>(
                    value: standard,
                    child: Text(standard.standardName),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onSaved: (value) {
                  selectedStandard = value;
                  //this.userRegistration.standardId = value!.standardId;
                },
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedStandard = val;
                    standardId = val?.standardId;
                    // print("StandardId : ${val?.standardId}");
                    // print("StandardId : ${val?.standardName}");
                    onMediumChange(val);
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              DropdownButtonFormField<Medium>(
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null) {
                      return "Select Medium";
                    }
                  },
                  isExpanded: true,
                  hint: Text('Select Medium'),
                  value: selectedMedium,
                  items: _mediums.map((Medium medium) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<Medium>(
                      value: medium,
                      child: Text(medium.mediumName),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    selectedMedium = value;
                    //this.userRegistration.mediumId = value!.mediumId;
                  },
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedMedium = val;
                      mediumId = val?.mediumId;
                      // print("Medium id : ${val?.mediumId}");
                      // print("Medium id : ${val?.mediumName}");
                    });
                  }),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (validateAndSave()) {
                        setState(() {
                          this.isApiCallProcess = true;
                          print(_nameController.text);
                          print(_emailController.text);
                          print(_mobileController.text);
                          print(standardId);
                          print(mediumId);
                          userRegistration = ApiManager().createUser(
                            _nameController.text,
                            _emailController.text,
                            _mobileController.text,
                            standardId,
                            mediumId,
                          );
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25))),
                    child: Ink(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              const Color(0xff8921aa),
                              const Color(0xffDA44bb),
                            ],
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 50,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          'SIGNUP',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 60,
              ),
              Text('Already have an account?'),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login2()));
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    foreground: new Paint()..shader = linearGradient,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool validateAndSave() {
    final form = _globalFormKey.currentState;
    if (form!.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

So, when i try to sign up it thorows an Exception as below.
So what is the problem in given code.?
[image]

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767696/13997210) answer for Post data to API

Comment: not working, it executed else part of function

Comment: response code 500

Comment: can you tell me what was the error, because 500 means Internal server error and what is the error?

Comment: before checking the condition i print the response.body which executed successfully and prints the body. but next i print the response.statuscode which execute the error code 500. which means not success. when i try to post man it works

Comment: can you share your API url I will test it? and what was the error? or if you pass this url from postman its working proper or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236633/discussion-between-ravindra-s-patil-and-dhaval-chaudhari).

Comment: but sir, my api on local server.

Comment: ok No issue can you add your response? like `{     "Status": "1",     "Message": "You are registered successfully",     "UserData": {         "Name": "qwert@gmail.com",         "EncUserId": "evaCGQUWUt6RPoU6ODXDsQ=="     } }`

Comment: hello sir,
in postman the data is passed as form-data so for that same method can used or other?

Comment: are you on linkedin?

Comment: yes i am on linkedin

Comment: Hello Sir, I Done it. Form-Data can be send using dio. And i Successfully done it.

Comment: most welcome ,@
Dhaval Chaudhari