# how to use POST method in dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, postman, http-post

I want to send a request to server and get details, i have written some code but i don't know why it doesn't work.
i found out that the reason is that the my variables won't be sent to server and i don't know where is problem.
here is my codes :

```
  _sendBuyBtnReq(
      {required BuildContext context,
      required String Amount,
      required String ScoreAmount}) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var toke = prefs.getString('mykey');
    var ide = prefs.getString('mykey');

    final url = Uri.parse('my url');
    var body = Map<String, dynamic>();

    body["CustomerId"] = '$ide';
    body["Amount"] = '$Amount';
    body["Credit"] = '$ScoreAmount';
    body["Description"] = '2';

    http.Response response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $toke'
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(await response.body.toString());
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
      var messageM = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
      var MessageModel = messageModel(messageM['message']);
      // print(MessageModel._message);
      showSnackBar7(context, MessageModel.message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767696/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Comment: you never passed the body into your request, I believe adding `body: jsonEncode(body)` should fix your problem

Comment: @h8moss Yes you right i haven't passed body,  also `body: jsonEncode(body)`  didn't work.

Comment: @NavidShokoufeh why did it not work? Does it work if you just don't use it?

Comment: @h8moss I used your solution but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass body to the request

and make sure your `url` is working

**try this**

```
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var toke = prefs.getString('mykey');
    var ide = prefs.getString('mykey');
    final url = Uri.parse('my url'); //pass proper url
    var body = Map<String, dynamic>();
    
    body["CustomerId"] = '$ide';
    body["Amount"] = '$Amount';
    body["Credit"] = '$ScoreAmount';
    body["Description"] = '2';

    http.Response response = await http.post(
          url,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $toke'
          },
         body: body,
        );


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       print(response.body.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a body parameter, and that is why your `POST` request is considered as incomplete. Try this code out.

```
_sendBuyBtnReq(
      {required BuildContext context,
      required String Amount,
      required String ScoreAmount}) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var toke = prefs.getString('mykey');
    var ide = prefs.getString('mykey');

    final url = Uri.parse('my url');
    var body = Map<String, dynamic>();

    body["CustomerId"] = '$ide';
    body["Amount"] = '$Amount';
    body["Credit"] = '$ScoreAmount';
    body["Description"] = '2';

    http.Response response = await http.post(
      url,
      body: json.encode(body),
      headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $toke'
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(await response.body.toString());
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
      var messageM = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
      var MessageModel = messageModel(messageM['message']);
      // print(MessageModel._message);
      showSnackBar7(context, MessageModel.message);
    }
}
```