# Flutter, How to use laravel API for flutter login

Tags: flutter

Im new to flutter and currently work as an intern in a small company, I'm trying to get API from laravel and try to login in flutter. Is there anyone can assist me to have a look on my code? I will write them below.

I'm trying to test it without token, but on online tutorial everyone is having token.

**api.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Network{
  final String _url = 'http://192.168.0.138:8000/api/';
  var token;

  _getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    token = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('token'))['token'];
  }

  authData(data, apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl;
    return await http.post(
        fullUrl,
        body: jsonEncode(data),
        headers: _setHeaders()
    );
  }

  getData(apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl;
    await _getToken();
    return await http.get(
        fullUrl,
        headers: _setHeaders()
    );
  }

  _setHeaders() => {
    'Content-type' : 'application/json',
    'Accept' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer $token'
  };

}
```

**Login_Screen**

```
import 'package:ezymember/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:ezymember/screens/register_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:ezymember/network_utils/api.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var member_email;
  var member_password;
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  _showMsg(msg) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(msg),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'Close',
        onPressed: () {
          // Some code to undo the change!
        },
      ),
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: const Text('Hello',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 175.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: const Text('There',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(220.0, 175.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: const Text('.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 80.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.blue)),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'EMAIL',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                      ),
                      validator: (emailValue) {
                        if (emailValue.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter email';
                        }
                        member_email = emailValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'PASSWORD',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                      ),
                      validator: (passwordValue) {
                        if (passwordValue.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please Enter Password';
                        }
                        member_password = passwordValue;
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: FlatButton(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 8, bottom: 8, left: 10, right: 10),
                          child: Text(
                            _isLoading ? 'Proccessing...' : 'Login',
                            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            _login();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text(
                  'New to EzyMember ?',
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => RegisterPage()));
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'Register',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ),
    );
  }

  void _login() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    var data = {'email': member_email, 'password': member_password};

    var res = await Network().authData(data, '/login');
    var body = json.decode(res.body);
    if (body['success']) {
      SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      localStorage.setString('token', json.encode(body['token']));
      localStorage.setString('user', json.encode(body['user']));
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
      );
    } else {
      _showMsg(body['message']);
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767696/13997210) hope its help to  you In this answer I have used registration same you can used Login