# Flutter API giving error when i post to MYSQL

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to login using MYSQL and PHP , When i type the below code? The url is highlighted and says **The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.**

```
Future login() async {
        var url = "https://12.12.12.21/api/login.php";
        var response = await http.post(url, body: {
          "username":  _email,
          "password": _password,
        });
```

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767696/13997210) hope its helpful to you. try same as Login functionallity

Answer (score 0):

```
Future login() async {
            var url = Uri.parse("https://12.12.12.21/api/login.php");
            var response = await http.post(url, body: {
              "username":  _email,
              "password": _password,
            });
```