# Flutter Post Data To Json Api

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-desktop

I have a json api. Like this 'https://myapiurl.com/api.json'. I can read data in this api and I can fetch data in my app. But i can't post data in the my api. Here my source code.

I am fetching data this way.

```html
Future<List<Stock>> getStock() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://myapiurl.com/api.json"));
    var _stocks = <Stock>[];
    _stocks = (json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)) as List)
        .map((singleStockMap) => Stock.fromJson(singleStockMap))
        .toList();
    return _stocks;
  }
```

And i am trying this way for post data.

```html
postData() async {
    try {
      var response = await http
          .post(Uri.parse("https://myapiurl.com/api.json"), body: {
        "productName": 1.toString(),
        "productStock": "Hello",
      });
      print(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

What is wrong?

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767696/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: It returns successfully. But still it is not writing the data to my api file. Why could that be?

Comment: are you print your data to console and check statuscode also

Comment: Yes I did it. No problem here but it is not writing the data to my api file.

Comment: can you tell me your api url is hosted I will check on my machine. and give me the column name also

Comment: And i am developing for flutter desktop. Maybe thats important info.

Comment: can you tell me which method do you have for this API get or post I tried this url it gives me the data but not statuscode

Comment: What means which method sir? And i can access status code with your answer. Status code 200 in debug console.

Comment: hey bro I have try your URL it gives the 200 status code but data is not inserted , I also try this Postman also but not work I think this url is made by GET method not POST method try to make  it POST method

Comment: Sorry i will try another way for data situations. Maybe i can use PhpMyAdmin or Firebase. I was try API because I think this so basic but thats not seems simple

Answer (score 0):

you have to encode your body before passing it:

passBody = json.encode(body);

Comment: I am not understand. Can u explain pls?

Comment: You can't send your json as is, just enconde it before sending it