# How can I run register and login in Flutter with api?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have written Sign up and Login with the Laravel (API), but I want this operation to be performed in Flutter. I do not know which way to use it.

For example, in react we use axios for `get` or `post` data. In Flutter what is the equivalent?

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767696/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Dart has an [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package that you can use to make api requests.
The flutter [documentation] walks through how you can add that package and use it to make requests from your app.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
Future<http.Response> fetchAlbum() {
  return http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));
}
```

You'll also need add the http package as a dependency and add internet permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries in pub.dev, such as dio and http.
Those are the common libraries that I use, and they also provide methods to set parameters and other things.

Example use:

```
Dio client = DioClient().getClient(base_url, 15000, 15000);
client.options.headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};
try {
  var response =
      await client.get(link_after_base_url_before_parameters, queryParameters: params);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    ResponseDto responseDto = ResponseDto.fromJson(response.data);
  }
} catch(e) {}
```

Check this out:

> https://pub.dev/packages/dio

> https://pub.dev/packages/http