# Flutter is not posting my question to the API

Tags: flutter

I have this register page in Flutter but it is not updating my database...

My API is fine, when using something like postman and sending the exact same JSON, my database gets updated, so the issue is with the code below:

```
postData() async {
  print('entered postDAta');
  var response = http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup"),
      body: {
        "username": "flota",
        "email": "hay@flut.com",
        "password": "87654321",
      }
  );
  print('exited postdata');
}
```

and

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: postData,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
```

FULL CODE JUST IN CASE

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
import 'dart:core';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'Widget/bezierContainer.dart';
import 'loginPage.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

postData() async {
  print('entered postDAta');
  var response = http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup"),
      body: {
        "username": "flota",
        "email": "hay@flut.com",
        "password": "87654321",
      }
  );
  print('exited postdata');
}

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SignUpPage({Key ?key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _SignUpPageState createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  Widget _backButton() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 10, bottom: 10),
              child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            Text('Back',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _entryField(String title, {bool isPassword = false}) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextField(
              obscureText: isPassword,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  fillColor: Color(0xfff3f3f4),
                  filled: true))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _submitButton() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                offset: Offset(2, 4),
                blurRadius: 5,
                spreadRadius: 2)
          ],
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [Color(0xfffbb448), Color(0xfff7892b)])),
      child: Text(
        'Register Now',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _loginAccountLabel() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Already have an account ?',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              'Login',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xfff79c4f),
                  fontSize: 13,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _title() {
    return RichText(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      text: TextSpan(
          text: 'd',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              color: Color(0xffe46b10)
          ),

          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: 'ev',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: 'rnz',
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffe46b10), fontSize: 30),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }

  Widget _emailPasswordWidget() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _entryField("Username"),
        _entryField("Email id"),
        _entryField("Password", isPassword: true),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: height,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: -MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .15,
              right: -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
              child: BezierContainer(),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height: height * .2),
                    _title(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    _emailPasswordWidget(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    _submitButton(),
                    SizedBox(height: height * .14),
                    _loginAccountLabel(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(top: 40, left: 0, child: _backButton()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: postData,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it solve if you replace `var response = http.post` with `var response = await http.post`?

Comment: nope @enzo thanks anyway

Comment: is there any error log when this API is called? If any can you add the error log in console

Comment: If you try registration refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767696/13997210) hope its helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when we send data to server in mobile mostly is the raw format. for that we have to use 'jsonEncode' for converting and we have to set header.

```
   postData() async {
     print('entered postDAta');
       var response = await http.post(
       Uri.parse("http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup"),
      body: jsonEncode({
       "username": "flota",
       "email": "hay@flut.com",
      "password": "87654321",
      }),headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
   );
   print(response.body);
    print('exited postdata');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
postData() async {
  print('entered postDAta');
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup"),
      body: {
        "username": "flota",
        "email": "hay@flut.com",
        "password": "87654321",
      }
  );
  print('exited postdata');
}
```

use `await` before http.post. I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have got your answer, Here's some resources to understand the flow of API methods-

You can go through the official website to handle APIs in flutter-

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

and here's a good documentation of basic flow of API integration-

https://mobikul.com/http-api-calling-in-flutter/