# REST Api Login With POST Method

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I wanted to do the classic login with a JSON but it does not work, in the sense that even if you put the wrong credentials from 200 (ie ok). I only put a JSON file (login.json), at this point I doubt that we need to create a particular environment to manage the JSON .. the server where the JSON resides is a HOSTING on the L.A.M.P. (Linux / Apache / MySQL / PHP)

#### login_page.dart

```
        import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_http_post_request/api/api_service.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_http_post_request/model/login_model.dart';
    
    import '../ProgressHUD.dart';
    
    class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
    }
    
    class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
      bool hidePassword = true;
      bool isApiCallProcess = false;
      GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      LoginRequestModel loginRequestModel;
      final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        loginRequestModel = new LoginRequestModel();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ProgressHUD(
          child: _uiSetup(context),
          inAsyncCall: isApiCallProcess,
          opacity: 0.3,
        );
      }
    
      Widget _uiSetup(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: scaffoldKey,
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 20),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 85, horizontal: 20),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Theme.of(context).hintColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                              offset: Offset(0, 10),
                              blurRadius: 20)
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Form(
                        key: globalFormKey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(height: 25),
                            Text(
                              "Login",
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            new TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              onSaved: (input) => loginRequestModel.email = input,
                              validator: (input) => !input.contains('@')
                                  ? "Email Id should be valid"
                                  : null,
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Email Address",
                                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                            .accentColor
                                            .withOpacity(0.2))),
                                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)),
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.email,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            new TextFormField(
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              onSaved: (input) =>
                                  loginRequestModel.password = input,
                              validator: (input) => input.length < 3
                                  ? "Password should be more than 3 characters"
                                  : null,
                              obscureText: hidePassword,
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Password",
                                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                            .accentColor
                                            .withOpacity(0.2))),
                                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)),
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.lock,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                ),
                                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      hidePassword = !hidePassword;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  color: Theme.of(context)
                                      .accentColor
                                      .withOpacity(0.4),
                                  icon: Icon(hidePassword
                                      ? Icons.visibility_off
                                      : Icons.visibility),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30),
                            FlatButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 12, horizontal: 80),
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (validateAndSave()) {
                                  print(loginRequestModel.toJson());
    
                                  setState(() {
                                    isApiCallProcess = true;
                                  });
    
                                  APIService apiService = new APIService();
                                  apiService.login(loginRequestModel).then((value) {
                                    if (value != null) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isApiCallProcess = false;
                                      });
    
                                      if (value.token.isNotEmpty) {
                                        final snackBar = SnackBar(
                                            content: Text("Login Successful"));
                                        scaffoldKey.currentState
                                            .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                                      } else {
                                        final snackBar =
                                            SnackBar(content: Text(value.error));
                                        scaffoldKey.currentState
                                            .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                                      }
                                    }
                                  });
                                }
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "Login",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                              shape: StadiumBorder(),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 15),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      bool validateAndSave() {
        final form = globalFormKey.currentState;
        if (form.validate()) {
          form.save();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }

api_service.dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import '../model/login_model.dart';

class APIService {
  Future<LoginResponseModel> login(LoginRequestModel requestModel) async {
    //String url = "https://reqres.in/api/login";
    String url = "https://www.nextesa.it/api/login";

    final response = await http.post(url, body: requestModel.toJson());
    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 400) {
      return LoginResponseModel.fromJson(
        json.decode(response.body),
      );
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data!');
    }
  }
}
```

#### login_mode.dart

```
class LoginResponseModel {
  final String token;
  final String error;

  LoginResponseModel({this.token, this.error});

  factory LoginResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginResponseModel(
      token: json["token"] != null ? json["token"] : "",
      error: json["error"] != null ? json["error"] : "",
    );
  }
}

class LoginRequestModel {
  String email;
  String password;

  LoginRequestModel({
    this.email,
    this.password,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'email': email.trim(),
      'password': password.trim(),
    };

    return map;
  }
}
```

#### File json

```
{
    "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
    "password": "cityslicka"
}
```

Comment: It's from API side. Ask the backend developer, why I am getting 200 even credentials is wrong.

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767696/13997210) in this answer I write registration code try same as login, hope its help to you

Comment: Since we do not control the backend, we cannot tell you why it behaves the way it does. Consult the documentation and if you have a support contract, ask their support. If it's inhouse, give the developer a call.

Comment: First of all thanks for the replies ... but couldn't it be the structure of the json? I only uploaded this  

{
    "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
    "password": "cityslicka"
}