# Flutter data not post to API

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-http

I tried to post some data through API but every time the response is failed i don't knoow why the response is failed because if i normally hit the API in it show me the success response but i hit the API on press button it shows me response Failed.

Here is my code :-

Register.dart :

```
void main() => runApp(const Register());
class Register extends StatelessWidget {
const Register({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
const double padding = 25;
const sidePadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: padding);
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      padding: sidePadding,
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      child: Center(
        child: RegisterForm(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}

class RegisterForm extends StatefulWidget {
const RegisterForm({super.key});

@override
_RegisterForm createState() => _RegisterForm();
}

class _RegisterForm extends State<RegisterForm> {
TextEditingController _name = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _mobileno = new TextEditingController();
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      TextFormField(
        controller: _name,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Technician Name',
            labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xfff9a28f),
            ),
        ),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
      TextFormField(
        controller: _mobileno,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Enter Mobile Number',
            labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xfff9a28f),
            ),
        ),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter more some text';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
              RegisterController(
                name: _name.text,
                mobileno: _mobileno.text,
              ).addRegisterAPI().then((value) {
                print('Response: $value');
              });
            }
          },
          child: Text(
                'Register',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

registercontroller.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


class RegisterController {
 final String name;
final String mobileno;

RegisterController({required this.name, required this.mobileno});

Future<String> addRegisterAPI()  async{
try{
  final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("https://********.in/index.php?"), body :{
      'act': "register",
      'name': name,
      'mobile': mobileno,
      });
  if(response.statusCode ==  200){
    final result  = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return result;
  } else {
    return "fail";
  }
} catch (e) {
  return "failed";
}
}
}
```

when `onPressed` hit `RegisterController()` it print the `Response: failed` i don't know why the `RegisterController()` goes in `catch (e)` and print `Response: failed`

fir any one knows how to solve this please help me

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767696/13997210) for **Submit data to API**

Comment: is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: please check or compare my answer

Comment: what you get when print the `e` .

Comment: it wil more informatif , when you `print(e)` instead of `print(failed)`

Comment: when i print `e` it show me `I/flutter (12559): HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:` 
`I/flutter (12559):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate(handshake.cc:393))` what does that means?

Comment: now you know the error.  try this :  https://stackoverflow.com/q/54285172/12838877

Comment: ok i fixed the the `certificate` now the `statusCode` is `200` but also it throw the same error

Comment: now when i print the `e` it shows me `Response: FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)` error

Answer (score 0):

did you miss the jsonEncode in the body?

```
 final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("https://********.in/index.php?"), body :jsonEncode({
      'act': "register",
      'name': name,
      'mobile': mobileno,
      })
   );
```

Comment: same error show with this

Answer (score 0):

```
 final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse("https://********.in/index.php?"), 
  headers: <String, String>{
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },  
  body :jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
  'act': "register",
  'name': name,
  'mobile': mobileno,
  }));
```

if it did not help, print the error for more information.