# Trying to send data to API using model and list in flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, api, error-handling, model

I am trying to send data to API, But I can't make it to work. I use model to get data from users.

Here is the model

```
   class SurgeryModel {
  String id;
  String name;
  DateTime date;
  String eye;

  SurgeryModel(
      {required this.id,
      required this.date,
      required this.name,
      required this.eye});

  
}
```

And I am adding data like this.

```
    void addNewSurgeryRecord(BuildContext ctx) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          // we use statefulbilder because we need to use setState to update the dropdown menu state.
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  10.0,
                ),
              ),
              content: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'Surgery Name',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          maxLength: 1000,
                          maxLines: null,
                          controller: sNameController,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                15.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                            // labelText: 'Drug name',
                            // labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[200]),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                15.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'Date',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextFieldContainer(
                          child: DateTimeField(
                            format: format,
                            onChanged: (getPrescriptionDate) {
                              formattedTodate = getPrescriptionDate!;
                            },
                            onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
                              return showDatePicker(
                                  context: context,
                                  firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                                  initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
                                  lastDate: DateTime(2100));
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: 'Select Date of Visited',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                            ),
                            initialValue: formattedTodate.toLocal(),
                            validator: (dateOfBirthValue) {
                              // dob = dateOfBirthValue.toString();
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        // TextFieldContainer(
                        //   keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        //   maxLength: 1000,
                        //   maxLines: null,
                        //   // controller: surgeryDateController,
                        //   decoration: InputDecoration(
                        //     border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        //       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        //         15.0,
                        //       ),
                        //     ),
                        //     focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        //       borderRadius:
                        //           BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                        //       borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                        //     ),
                        //     // labelText: 'Drug name',
                        //     // labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[200]),
                        //     enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        //       borderSide: BorderSide(
                        //         color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        //       ),
                        //       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        //         15.0,
                        //       ),
                        //     ),
                        //   ),
                        // ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            'Eye',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextFieldContainer(
                          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                            child: DropdownButton(
                              icon: Visibility(
                                  visible: false,
                                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
                              isExpanded: true,
                              value: dropDownValue,
                              items: eyeSide.map((value) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: value,
                                  child: Text(value),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              onChanged: ((String? value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  print(value);
                                  dropDownValue = value!;
                                  print(' print 2$value');
                                });
                              }),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        // TextField(
                        //   keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        //   maxLength: 1000,
                        //   maxLines: null,
                        //   controller: sEyeController,
                        //   decoration: InputDecoration(
                        //     border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        //       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        //         15.0,
                        //       ),
                        //     ),
                        //     focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        //       borderRadius:
                        //           BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                        //       borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                        //     ),
                        //     // labelText: 'Drug name',
                        //     // labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[200]),
                        //     enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        //       borderSide: BorderSide(
                        //         color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        //       ),
                        //       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        //         15.0,
                        //       ),
                        //     ),
                        //   ),
                        // ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              actions: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.green,
                      onPrimary: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      widget.addSurgery(
                        sNameController.text,
                        dropDownValue,
                        formattedTodate,
                      );
                      // _addNewSurgery(sNameController.text, sEyeController.text);
                      print(sNameController.text);
                      print(sEyeController.text);
                      print(formattedTodate.toString());
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text('Done'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
        });
  }
```

Below function is in another screen I pass this function to the above code screen.

```
    void _addNewSurgery(String sName, String sEye, DateTime date) {
    final newProp = SurgeryModel(
      date: date,
      name: sName,
      eye: sEye,
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
    );

    setState(() {
      widget.surgeData.add(newProp);
    });
  }
```

With help of these codes I am sending data to the web like below code

```
    testFunction() async {
    var localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    

    var data = {
   
      'surgeryHistory ': surgeData.toList(),
     
    };

    print('viewing pres data $data');
    var res = await Network().authData(data, '/route');
    debugPrint('printing before response ${res.body}');
    var body = json.decode(res.body);
    debugPrint('printing coming response ${body}');
   
  }
```

I am getting this data like this on the web side(in laravel)

```
 public function testWebFunction(Request $request)
    {
        
        $surgery_history = $request->get('surgeryHistory');
        $surgery_history_index = $surgery_history;

        return $surgery_history;

    }
```

But I am getting error like this,

[image: Error like this]

Am I doing something wrong here? I need to get those data to the web and save that data in to the database using for loop. In backend side I am using foreach to save data but i cant get sizeof the variable. Any answer will help me to overcome this situation. Thank You.

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767696/13997210) hope its help to you, I have send data to server or refer documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data)

Comment: @KavindaLochana can you say what is the type of `res` when you hover on it?

Comment: you mean var res = await Network().authData(data, '/route'); this line? It's dynamic.

Comment: can you include authData code?